# Android, overwrite items view in ListView to display slightly different to actual value

Tags: java, android, android-listview

So in my listview I have a bunch of strings, but I'd like to display the values with £ in front of the strings, but NOT actually edit the values themselves in the ArrayList.

Anyone know how I can do this?

I'm already overwriting the view anyway, I'm just not sure how to alter the display of the items values themselves.

Some Code:

```
adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);  



                if (position % 2 != 0) 
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(135,206,250)); // Pale blue

        return view;  

    }
    });

    foodListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.foodListView);
    foodListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you `getView` method you can use:

```
    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    text.setText("£" + listItems.get(position));
```

Comment: Can't seem to do that.. I want to do it to all of them. Also I don't have a designated textview for each item. It's just linked to the adapter and I add to the Array to populate.

Comment: I added it to the original post.